# Caliburn Micro - How can I inject dependencies into a ViewModel without requiring all its ancestors to have the same dependencies?

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I'm getting started with the Caliburn Micro Framework, and I'm running into a problem that I imagine the framework authors probably have a solution for, though I can't see what it is.

Say I have a parent ViewModel than needs to create one ore more child ViewModels at runtime.

**How can my child ViewModels resolve their dependencies without the parent having the same dependencies?**

Property Injection would save my parent VMs from having to know about their children's dependencies, but that only works for interface properties, and if I litter the code with a bunch of useless interfaces to accommodate Dependency Injection then I'm just trading one problem for another.

Comment: Can't you use composition instead? i.e. move the shared methods to a separate class which every view model uses? In that way you only have to take that class as a dependency

Comment: I'm not sure what shared methods have to do with it.

The problem I'm trying to address is that in order for a parent VM to instantiate a child VM, the parent has to obtain instances of all the child's dependencies, and then pass those instances into the child.  This leads to the root level view having tons of properties that aren't relevant to the root view, but to its descendents.  I'm sure the framework authors have provided a better solution, but I'm not sure exactly what it is

Comment: I'm considering adding the SimpleContainer as a dependency for all my ViewModels, so they can use it as a factory and thereby bypass the need to know about their children's dependencies, but it seems like if that were the intended solution the framework authors would have already included ways to access the container in the Screen, or NotifyPropertyChangedBase classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get around this with MEF or you can use SimpleContainer but you don't need to have SC as a dependency since if you are using it as your container the framework already knows about it with the use of IoC static class.  It has a Get() method.  That will pull the type your are looking for. The catch is it has to be in the container.  IoC doesn't care if it is SimpleContainer or MEF more or less container abstracted.

`var sometype = IoC.Get<ThatType>();`

MEF will allow for [Import] as a property as long as the class being called is correctly decorated and is successfully pulled into the MEF Container at buildup.

MEF is far more powerful and it can do dependencies if done right, but it has its own idiosyncrasies as well.

hth

Answer (score 0):

The Factory pattern would be one way. Another could be the use of a DI container to resolve the dependencies on the child ViewModels if those dependencies were interfaces.

Property injection might be another means to assist you e.g.

```
public void SomeProperty(ISomeInterface aDependency) 
{
    // use the dependency. Dependency Not required when object creation
}
```

or lazy loading of properties on the child ViewModels could also help e.g.

```
private ISomeInterface aDependency;

public ISomeInterface MyDependency
{
    get 
    { 
        if (aDependency == null)
            aDependecy = new SomeConcreteClass();
        return aDependency;
    }
    set { aDependency = value; }
}
```